# Run Windows Store Application from Desktop

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-10

I am trying to launch a Windows Store application from a C# Windows Forms App on Windows 10. I tried some approaches what (probably?) works on Windows 8 but don't work on 10.
I tried as follows:

```
Process.Start("explorer", @"shell:AppsFolder\AppUserModelId")
```

or

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit\Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.AppxLauncher.exe", "AppUserModelId");
or IApplicationActivationManager::ActivateApplication
```

This works, but only from the command line (which tells me that using AppUserModelId is correct).

Anyone knows a working solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found this article of creating desktop shortcuts of store apps: http://winaero.com/blog/exclusive-how-to-start-a-modern-app-from-desktop-without-going-to-the-metro-start-screen/

Sorry that I couldn't help any more than that.